# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) usando windows subsystem for linux

Tags: mysql, wsl

Quiero connectarme a mi base de datos mysql usando wsl:

```
(dat_env) ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Aqui esta `my.cnf`

```
(dat_env) ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

No sé si el socket esté bien definido ...

Comment: MySQL está siendo ejecutada en Windows o en tu subsistema Linux?

Comment: Normalmente se ejecuta en Windows, pero aquí he probado con WSL, @PabloLozano

Comment: Lo comento porque yo he tenido ese mismo problema cuando he intentado acceder a una instancia corriendo en un docker local: mySQL por defecto intenta conectarse a la instancia local con sockets que no son "network sockets", sino para comunicaciones entre procesos

Comment: Bien, ¿qué sugieres que haga? ¿Probar desde Windows? El objetivo de la manipulación de WSL era hacerlo sin Windows porque parece que [tengo errores de dependencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465797/cannot-open-include-file-my-config-h-no-such-file-or-directory-al-installar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que deberías poderte conectar si usas las siguientes opciones:

```sh
mysql -h localhost -u root  --protocol=tcp
```

De este modo se usarán TCP sockets en lugar de "process sockets"

Comment: Por desgracia obtengo `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Si, eso es más normal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost