# OSError: mysql_config not found al installar mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, librería, fedora

Quiero instalar una biblioteca en mi entorno virtual en Fedora para connectarme a MySQL:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dt7pv4kk
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/ff/4e964e20b559e55d7afa60fbccc6a560f2adf289813bd3d7eb4eb8a87093/mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz#sha256=c74a83b4cb2933d0e43370117eeebdfa03077ae72686d2df43d31879267f1f1b (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==1.3.7 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==1.3.7
```

No sé qué error ha provocado éste, si es el hecho de no encontrar la librería `mysqlclient==1.3.7` o si es `OSError: mysql_confignot found` ...

## `yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
[sudo] password for ac: 
Fedora 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                    54 kB/s |  24 kB     00:00    
Fedora 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                   1.1 MB/s | 2.4 MB     00:02    
Fedora Modular 34 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                            36 kB/s |  24 kB     00:00    
Package python3-devel-3.9.5-2.fc34.x86_64 is already installed.
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.i686
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.i686 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.i686
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.i686 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64
  - conflicting requests
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.i686
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.i686 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.i686
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.i686 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.x86_64
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.x86_64
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.9-5.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb-devel provided by mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64
  - package mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql-devel provided by community-mysql-devel-8.0.23-2.fc34.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel --allowerasing
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:43 ago on Mon 05 Jul 2021 10:15:01 AM CEST.
Package python3-devel-3.9.5-2.fc34.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Architecture                      Version                                      Repository                           Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mariadb-devel                                        x86_64                            3:10.5.11-1.fc34                             updates                             1.0 M
Installing dependencies:
 mariadb-connector-c-devel                            x86_64                            3.1.13-1.fc34                                updates                              55 k
Removing dependent packages:
 community-mysql-devel                                x86_64                            8.0.25-1.fc34                                @updates                            364 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages
Remove   1 Package

Total download size: 1.0 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-1.fc34.x86_64.rpm                                                                                      488 kB/s |  55 kB     00:00    
(2/2): mariadb-devel-10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                 2.2 MB/s | 1.0 MB     00:00    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                          831 kB/s | 1.0 MB     00:01     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                       1/1 
  Installing       : mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                        1/3 
  Installing       : mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                                 2/3 
  Erasing          : community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                            3/3 
  Running scriptlet: community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                            3/3 
  Verifying        : mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                        1/3 
  Verifying        : mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                                 2/3 
  Verifying        : community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                            3/3 

Installed:
  mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-1.fc34.x86_64                                             mariadb-devel-3:10.5.11-1.fc34.x86_64                                            
Removed:
  community-mysql-devel-8.0.25-1.fc34.x86_64                                                                                                                                   

Complete!
```

## Aviso

mi experiencia con mysqlclient es un verdadero desastre:

Con Fedora:

- Con la libreria mysqlclient==1.3.7 (celle du serveur Debian):
  `mysql_config` falta, incluso al reinstalar conectores como `mariadb-connector-c-devel` o `community-mysql-devel` **[esta pregunta]**
- Con la libreria 2.0.3:
  [MySQL-python falta, o no se reconoce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466382/instalar-mysqlclient2-en-fedora-pero-no-se-encuentra-la-biblioteca)

Con Windows:

- Con la librairia `mysqlclient==1.3.7` ,
  [imposible de instalar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465797/cannot-open-include-file-my-config-h-no-such-file-or-directory-al-installar): me dice que use Visual C++ pero no cambia nada. Así que he probado con una versión preconstruida del sitio de Christoph Gohlke pero no es compatible.
- Con >2.* obtengo:
  [`OperationalError: (2006, '')` en una gran parte de las consultas SQL como la siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465526/mysqldb-exceptions-operationalerror-2006-al-cerrar-una-consulta-sql-es):

```py
c.execute("""
        UPDATE `{table_name}` 
        SET `{column_name}` = CONCAT('hash_', {expression})
        WHERE {pk_name} IN ({ids})
    """.format(
        table_name=table_name, column_name=column_name, expression=expression, pk_name=pk_name,
        ids=','.join(ids)
    ))
```

Comment: Lo otro, ¿no puedes usar una versión más reciente? https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#history

Comment: El README pide que instales `yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`. Ya los tienes?

Comment: Mychas gracias para tu comentario @Alfabravo . Acabo de probarlo y me dice que ya tengo todo. He probado a instalar de nuevo la 1.3.7 y está sacando fallos. Creo que recurriré a una librería alternativa.